# how to move buy button underneath drop down box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move a button underneath the drop down box in my product page. so that the information is presented with one information per row. I tried placing a div tag around the button to see if that be seen as a separate element that goes below the previous element but that did not work so I am lost in what to do to make the buy button to go underneath the size and 1 boxes.

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
      <title>Responsive Sticky Navbar</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bike-1-style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="Menu">
            <header>

                <nav>

                <div class="menu-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="logo">
                        Croydon Cycles
                </div>

                <div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                                <li><a class="menu-text" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a class="menu-text" href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                                <li><a class="menu-text" href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                                <li><a class="menu-text" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                </nav>

            </header>
        </div>

        <div id="space"></div>


        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" >

<div class="wrapper"> 


  <div class="product group">
    <div class="col-1-2 product-image">
      <div class="bg"></div>
      <div class="indicator">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2 product-info">
      <h1>Field Notes Cherry Graph 3-Pack</h1>
      <h2>$877.50</h2>

      <div class="select-dropdown">
        <select>
          <option value="size">Size</option>
          <option value="size">Small</option>
          <option value="size">Medium</option>
          <option value="size">Large</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="select-dropdown">
        <select>
          <option value="quantity">1</option>
          <option value="quantity">2</option>
          <option value="quantity">3</option>
          <option value="quantity">4</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <br>
      <div class="Buy"></div> 

      <a href="" class="add-btn">Buy</a>
      </div>




      <ul>
        <li>Graph paper 40-page memo book.</li>
        <li>3 book per pack. Banded and shrink-wrapped</li>
        <li>Three great memo books worth fillin' up with information</li>
        <li>Red cherry wood covers</li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>

</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Menu-toggle button

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
    });
    // add this instruction !
    setTimeout(function() {plusSlides(1) }, 1000)
})

    // Scrolling Effect

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                $('nav').addClass('black');
        }

        else {
                $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
    })


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

    background-color:  #eee;

    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }

  h1{
    font-size: 130%;
  }

  h2{
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }


  p{
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

  /*.wrapper{
    padding: 20px 0px;
  }*/

  .content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}

nav.black .logo {
    color: #fff;
}

nav.black ul li a {
   color: #fff;
}

.menu-text {
    color: #000;
}

.logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index:2;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

    .logo {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          margin-top: 16px;
    }

    nav ul {
          max-height: 0px;
          background: #000;
    }

    nav.black ul {
          background: #000;
    }

    .showing {
          max-height: 34em;
    }

    nav ul li {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 24px;
          text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-icon {
          display: block;
    }

}

#space {
    width: 100%;
    height: 86px;
}

 .product{
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px 10% 70px 10%;
  }

  .group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }


  .col-1-2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }

  .product-image{
    /*border: 1px dotted #aaa;*/
  }

  .product-image .bg{
    background-image: url('images/slider-1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;

    min-height: 550px;
  }

  .product-image .indicator{
    text-align:center;
  }



  .dot:hover{
    background-color: #444;
  }

  .product-info{
    padding: 0px 8%;
  }

  .product-info h1{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .product-info h2{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .product-info .select-dropdown{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
  }

  .product-info select{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 12px 92px 12px 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
  }

  select:active, select:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .select-dropdown:after {
      content: " ";
    cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 30%;
    right: 10%;
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      border-left: 5px solid transparent;
      border-right: 5px solid transparent;
      border-top: 5px solid #aaa;
    }

  .product-info a.add-btn{
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 15px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
  }

  a.add-btn:hover{
    background-color: #555;
  }

  .product-info p{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .product-info p a{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #444;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
  }

  .product-info p a:hover{
    opacity: .7;
  }

  .product-info ul{
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .product-info li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .product-info li::before{
    content:"\2022";
    margin-right: 20px;
  }


  .product-info a.share-link{
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .product-info a.share-link:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
  }

#footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#222;
    padding: 60px 0px;
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 0;
    clear:both;
    height:10%;
}
```

Comment: There are more closing DIVs than opening DIVs in your markup. Try fixing that and adding your button to the _Buy_ div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong here.

1. The `<br>` tag should not be used for element positioning. This should be strictly reserved for text.
2. If you don't want your elements to display a line, it's probably a good idea to not set their `display` property to an `inline-block` for starters.
3. There are even some syntactical errors (eg. excessive `</div>` tag and what not). In general, I'd recommend writing your code in some sort of linter as it has some readability issues.

I did the baremost minimum of removing the unnecessary `<br>` tag and added `clear:both` to the `.Buy` class formatting. Producing the desired result.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 130%;
}

h2 {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


/*.wrapper{
    padding: 20px 0px;
  }*/

.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 4em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

nav.black .logo {
  color: #fff;
}

nav.black ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-text {
  color: #000;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;
  ;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.Buy {
  clear: both;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #000;
  }
  nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
  }
  .showing {
    max-height: 34em;
  }
  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
}

#space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
}

.product {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px 10% 70px 10%;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-1-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.product-image {
  /*border: 1px dotted #aaa;*/
}

.product-image .bg {
  background-image: url('images/slider-1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  min-height: 550px;
}

.product-image .indicator {
  text-align: center;
}

.dot:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

.product-info {
  padding: 0px 8%;
}

.product-info h1 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-info h2 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.product-info .select-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.product-info select {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 12px 92px 12px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

select:active,
select:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.select-dropdown:after {
  content: " ";
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #aaa;
}

.product-info a.add-btn {
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 15px 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

a.add-btn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.product-info p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-info p a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #444;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.product-info p a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.product-info ul {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.product-info li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-info li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.product-info a.share-link {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product-info a.share-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 60px 0px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  clear: both;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
  <title>Responsive Sticky Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bike-1-style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Menu">
    <header>

      <nav>

        <div class="menu-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="logo">
          Croydon Cycles
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="menu-text" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-text" href="location.html">Location</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-text" href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-text" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </header>
  </div>

  <div id="space"></div>


  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet">

  <div class="wrapper">


    <div class="product group">
      <div class="col-1-2 product-image">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="indicator">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1-2 product-info">
        <h1>Field Notes Cherry Graph 3-Pack</h1>
        <h2>$877.50</h2>

        <div class="select-dropdown">
          <select>
            <option value="size">Size</option>
            <option value="size">Small</option>
            <option value="size">Medium</option>
            <option value="size">Large</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="select-dropdown">
          <select>
            <option value="quantity">1</option>
            <option value="quantity">2</option>
            <option value="quantity">3</option>
            <option value="quantity">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>


        <div class="Buy"></div>

        <a href="" class="add-btn">Buy</a>
      </div>




      <ul>
        <li>Graph paper 40-page memo book.</li>
        <li>3 book per pack. Banded and shrink-wrapped</li>
        <li>Three great memo books worth fillin' up with information</li>
        <li>Red cherry wood covers</li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>

  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Menu-toggle button

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
        $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
      });
      // add this instruction !
      setTimeout(function() {
        plusSlides(1)
      }, 1000)
    })

    // Scrolling Effect

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').addClass('black');
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('black');
      }
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Turnip I kind of prefer the `<br/>` syntax for XHTML compatibility, though yeah here it is technically not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You have `<br/>` tag before button, just add style to it like this

```
<br style="clear: both;" />
```

and you should be fine :)

Comment: Everytime I do this I have the feeling that I am doing something wrong...

Comment: @lcssanches you shouldn't. You're essentially telling it , I don't want any floating elements on my left/right/both side. Though there is an argument to be made, that you perhaps could have used flexbox or better yet a grid instead of messing with the flow arbitrarily

Comment: @lcssanches You are. `br` tags should not be used in this way. They should only be used in text blocks to form a new line.

Comment: Well, yeah, to kind of clear out the confusion about me and @Turnip contradicting each other. I'm saying that you shouldn't be afraid of using `clear` as in whole. Using `br` tags for element indenting (`clear` or no `clear`) is indeed frowned up (and rightly so)

Comment: @lcssanches you wanted button below select box then do this, that was your question after all. If you need info about how to structure HTML document then read some blogs, but this answer resolves your problem.

Comment: I'm not criticizing you and it was not me who asked. But you clearly solve to question. But as @Turnip said, it is "allowed" only for text new line: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br